# Is it possible to have a variable with specific class reference type in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, superclass

Coming from a Delphi background, I am used to be able to have class references/pointers of a specific superclass, example:

```
#!pas
var
  niceVar: class of TClassOne; // Delphi style
  badVar: class; // Only? allowed AS3 style to the best of my knowledge

begin
  niceVar := x;
  badVar := x;

  niceVar.staticMethodSpecificToTClassOne;
  TClassOne(badVar).staticMethodSpecificToTClassOne;
end;
```

What this means is that I don't have to cast my variables to a specific class; they are of the correct Class beforehand.  This also means that compile-time checking can be performed to make sure proper members are being accessed and I don't have to check that niceVar is in fact of class TClassOne if niceVar was passed to a method.

```
#!pas
procedure test(var x: class of TClassOne);
begin
  x.someStaticMethod(true);
end;

// An entry point
var
  niceVar: TClassTwo; // Does not inherit from TClassOne

begin
  test(niceVar); // Error - niceVar does belong to the TClassOne "family"
end;
```

So just like a variable storing an object can be for a specific type and only objects of that class or subclasses of it are accepted, so to does "class of AClass" allow for variables of a specfic class to be limited to references to a certain class or those inherited from it.

I hope that makes sense somehow; I don't know of specific nomenclature for the whole "class of SuperClass" thing.

So I'd like to do the same in AS3 as having variables/properties/parameters of type Class does not cut the mustard; its kind of like having all object variables/properties/parameters simply being Object instead of their proper, specific type.

---

**Edit #1 - 2011-02-14 13:34**
Syntax highlighting is messed up here; I want the code to be recognized as Object Pascal.  Looking forward to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

---

**Edit #2 - 2011-02-14 15:11**
Here is an example of what I would like to achieve with this in AS3.

*Current code*

```
public function set recordClass(aRecordClass: Class): void 
{
  if (!extendsClass(aRecordClass, TRecord)) 
  {
    throw new Error("TDBTable - Invalid record class passed.");
      return;
  }
  _recordInstance = new aRecordClass(this); // Compiler has no idea of the classes constructor signature, but allows this regardless.
}
```

*What I'd like to be able to do*

```
public function set recordClass(aRecordClass: TRecordClass): void 
{
  _recordInstance = new aRecordClass(this); // Compiler will know that I am creating a TRecord
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `var myVariable:myClass;`?

Comment: That's for objects, not class references afaik.

Comment: I fixed up the code examples; they were making it look like I needed object references, but I want to be able to store *class* references and have them limited to superclass X for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you have to stay with `Class` type. This is one of ActionScript limitations, same as `Function` is reference for all function types. AS 3.0 quite often forces run-time checks where in other languages were static checks - static type checking is not its strongest point.

Comment: Yeah, thats true based on the info I have been able to find till now.  Was hoping for some better news though...  Maybe someone knows an almost-secret trick to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [getDefinitionByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29)

Comment: I'd rather not replace class references with strings, but yeah it is possible to derive class references based on name.  That is not what I am trying to achieve though; I'd like something the compiler can use pre-runtime.  Btw, as3commons.lang and as3commons.reflect offer some nice features to complement methods like getDefinitionByName.